# Import TextLMDataBunch from Fastai

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, fast-ai

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.jashds.com/blog/guide-to-text-classification-withnbspfastai) to build a NLP sentiment analysis model.

```
from fastai.text import *
```

This is the only import specified that includes fastai.

Unfortunately the [TextLMDataBunch](http://%20https://fastai1.fast.ai/text.data.html#TextLMDataBunch) is undefined.

What import should I used to have this class avaialable?

I have already tried:

```
from fastai.text.data import TextLMDataBunch
```

But apparently fastai.text.data is not even a package.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a tutorial of fast.ai v1 with the version 2 of the fastai library so it won't work. The link you've included in your question has the documentation for the class `TextMLDataBunch` but if you look at the url you will see that it is for `fastai1`.

https://fastai1.fast.ai/text.data.html

So you have two options, either you explicitely install fastai v1 or you find an alternative tutorial. This one may not be exactly what you're looking for but it could be a good starting point.

https://docs.fast.ai/tutorial.text.html

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this helps

```
from fastai.vision.data import ImageDataLoaders
```

Instead of using ImageDataBunch use data = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(path, valid_pct=0.2)

Check out the docs from https://docs.fast.ai/vision.data

Comment: I am looking to TextDataBunch not ImageDataBunch.